# Adding ntfs partition to fstab slows down boot time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, fstab

I have a 1TB SSD drive I created 3 main partitions for 120GB for windows, 120GB for linux, and ~500GB for a shared drive.

I partitioned the shared drive as NTFS and added this line to fstab

```
UUID=xxx    /media/data     ntfs-3g rw          0   0
```

This works in that the drive does get mounted but now booting into Ubuntu takes over a minute. 
I commented this line out and boot time was just at ~20secs.

I'm not even sure where to start here. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong and I still don't know where to start to check for error messages about this and whatnot but after more research I ended up following instructions I got online to use Ubuntu's Disks application.

It was pretty straightforward, just open up Disks, select your partition, click the gear button, and hit edit mount options:

[image: Disks mount options]

Select your mount options and it should add a line to your `fstab` file, mine looked this:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/<actual-uuid> /media/data auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Data 0 0
```

I should say though I did this a few days ago and I couldn't remember if the options were default or if I looked them up. I've been tinkering about with this OS so much, I honestly don't remember a lot o what I did.

So if someone more knowledgeable about these options shed light on it, I would appreciate an edit.